# How to create a custom parallel corpus for machine translation with recent versions of pytorch and torchtext?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, machine-translation, torchtext, torchdata

I am trying to train a model for NMT on a custom dataset. I found [this great tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6adRGJe5cQ&t) on youtube along with the [accompanying repo](https://github.com/aladdinpersson/Machine-Learning-Collection/blob/master/ML/Pytorch/more_advanced/seq2seq_transformer/seq2seq_transformer.py), but it uses an old version of PyTorch and torchtext. More recent versions of torchtext have removed the `Field` and `BucketIterator` classes.

I looked for more recent tutorials. The closest thing I could find was [this medium post](https://medium.com/@bitdribble/migrate-torchtext-to-the-new-0-9-0-api-1ff1472b5d71) (again with [the accompanying code](https://github.com/andrei-radulescu-banu/stat453-deep-learning-ss21/blob/main/L15/packed_lstm.ipynb)) which worked with a custom dataset for text classification. I tried to replicate the code with my problem and got this far:

```py
from os import PathLike
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchtext.vocab import Vocab
import pandas as pd
from .create_vocab import tokenizer


class ParallelCorpus(Dataset):
    """A parallel corpus for training a machine translation model"""

    def __init__(self,
                    corpus_path: str | PathLike,
                    source_vocab: Vocab,
                    target_vocab: Vocab
                    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.corpus = pd.read_csv(corpus_path)
        self.source_vocab = source_vocab
        self.target_vocab = target_vocab

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.corpus)

    def __getitem__(self, index: int):

        source_sentence = self.corpus.iloc[index, 0]
        source = [self.source_vocab["<sos>"]]
        source.extend(
            self.source_vocab.lookup_indices(tokenizer(source_sentence))
        )
        source.append(self.source_vocab["<eos>"])

        target_sentence = self.corpus.iloc[index, 1]
        target = [self.target_vocab["<sos>"]]
        target.extend(
            self.target_vocab.lookup_indices(tokenizer(target_sentence))
        )
        target.append(self.target_vocab["<eos>"])

        return source, target
```

My question is: is this the correct way to implement parallel corpora for pytorch? And where can I find more information about this since the documentation wasn't much help.

Thank you in advance and sorry if this is against the rules.